# Quartz scheduler with excluding specific time range

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule through Quartz scheduler excluding specific time ranges.

Ex : 2am - 3am and 5:30pm - 5:45pm

Is there any other way to achieve this without the use cron expression and cron scheduler?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the cron scheduler?

Also, I'm not 100% clear on what you want to archieve, could you rephrase your example please?

Comment: @dquijada I'm not good with cron expressions and want to know, is there any other libraries in quartz-scheduler api can do this job?

As at the end the cron expression will be parsed and it will set the parsed values to variables of an object.

So, assuming there should be some setter methods to do the same!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Quartz Calendars are used for. Since in your case you want to exclude specific **daytime** ranges, you will want to use the [DailyCalendar](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/calendar/DailyCalendar.html).

A single DailyCalendar can exclude a single day time range. Since you want to exclude multiple (two) ranges, you will need to combine two DailyCalendars like so:

```
// calendar that excludes the 2am-3am day time range
DailyCalendar dc1 = new DailyCalendar(2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0);

// calendar that excludes the 5:30pm-5:45pm day time range
DailyCalendar dc2 = new DailyCalendar(17,30,0,0,17,45,0,0);

// combine the two calendars so that both ranges are excluded by dc2
dc2.setBaseCalendar(dc1);

// register the calendar with the scheduler
scheduler.addCalendar("MyExcludedDayTimeRangesCalendar", dc2, true, true);

MutableTrigger trigger = ... create SimpleTrigger / CronTrigger  / DailyTimeInterval / CalendarIntervalTrigger instance

// associate the created trigger with the registered calendar - the trigger will exclude calendar's time ranges  
trigger.setCalendarName("MyExcludedDayTimeRangesCalendar");

...
```